# Cant figure out what is wrong with my models

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I set up my db like:

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize("sequel", "root", "root", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mysql",
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },
  logging: false
});

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

And my user model like this:

```js
const { Sequelize, sequelize } = require("../config/database");

const user = sequelize.define("users", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
  }
});

user.sync();

module.exports = user;
```

When I run server my error is this:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
near 'UUIDV4 NOT NULL , `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NUL' at line 1
    at Query.formatError (C:\Users\HP\Documents\sum\chiya\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:239:16)
    at Query.handler [as onResult] (C:\Users\HP\Documents\sum\chiya\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:46:23)
    at Query.execute (C:\Users\HP\Documents\sum\chiya\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:30:14)
    at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\HP\Documents\sum\chiya\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:449:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\HP\Documents\sum\chiya\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:72:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\HP\Documents\sum\chiya\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Documents\sum\chiya\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:79:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:226:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17)
```

As I am new to this what am I doing wrong to cause this syntax error??

And one extra thing if there is no table create one. I researched it but couldn't find anything that clearly so I used `user.sync()`. Is it even correct?

Answer (score 8):

I think the error is the data type you're using for the id column of your table. In the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html#static-variable-DataTypes) it shows that you should define your UUID column like this:

```
...
id: {
  type: Sequelize.UUID,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true
},
...
```

UUIDV4 is just a default unique identifier generated using the UUID v4 standard and should not be used as a data type.

> And one extra thing if there is no table create one. I researched it but couldn't find anything that clearly so I used user.sync(). Is it even correct?

As the documentation reports [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-sync), it is correct. The sync method is used to create the table if it doesn't exist on the database.

Comment: From the docs: "Three of the values provided here (NOW, UUIDV1 and UUIDV4) are special default values, that should not be used to define types. Instead they are used as shorthands for defining default values. For example, to get a uuid field with a default value generated following v1 of the UUID standard:"

You also need to update your `createdAt` definition